# Angular 4 - ¿Importar archivo JS con variables globales?

Tags: javascript, angular, web, webpack

Estoy trabajando con Angular 4 y mi problema es el siguiente:

Al momento de generar un paquete de producción con ng build --prod se genera mi carpeta dist y dentro de ella mi carpeta assets donde incluí un archivo JS llamado "ip.config.js". En este archivo tengo dos variables con las IP que utilizara el cliente para consumir las RESTful de su base de datos local.

Este archivo "ip.config.js" necesito constantemente actualizarlo con la IP que tenga cada cliente en su servidor. Pero al generar mi dist para producción las variables se quedan con el valor que tenían asignadas en ese momento.

La pregunta es: ¿Se puede configurar mi "ip.config.js" de alguna forma que las variables de este archivo se puedan modificar directamente en la carpeta dist y no tener que generar una distribución para cada cliente?.

Saludos cordiales!

Comment: Buenas, y si usas una función que obtenga la ip? algo como esto: $.getJSON('//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?', function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Solo que no debo ejecutar servicios de internet ya que mi app trabaja offline apuntando a una BD local

Comment: Se podría obtener desde la base? Saludos!

Comment: Desde mi back-end no seria posible pero ¿Sabes si es posible trabajar un servicio en node.js donde almacene de forma local esta IP y consumir este servicio al momento del login? y asi mandar mi IP al LocalStorage para utilizarla en toda mi app. ¿No chocaría si trabajo con node.js y el back-end donde tengo todos los servicios de mi app?

Answer (score 1):

### Opción 1

> Petición HTTP en vez de almacenar los datos en un fichero.

### Opción 2

> Utilizar variables de entorno por cada distribución.

Comment: En la opción 1 supongo que te refieres a hacer un servicio RestFul donde almacene estos datos y hacer el get al momento de hacer el login. Si es asi no me funcionaria ya que mi app trabaja en una BD local. No realizo peticiones externas.

Comment: Las variables de entorno no las he utilizado. Trabajare con ellas y te comento que tal me fue.